# missing semicolon at end of sql statement

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I have a problem when i m rum my code then error is occured "missing semicolon at end of sql statement."

My code is :

*Code*

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            FileUpload img = (FileUpload)imgUpload;
            Byte[] imgByte = null;
            if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)
            {
                //To create a PostedFile
                HttpPostedFile File = imgUpload.PostedFile;
                //Create byte Array with file len
                imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
                //force the control to load data in array
                File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
            }

            string str = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Geeta/Desktop/mssl2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";);


            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(str);

            conn.Open();
            string sql = "INSERT INTO digital(Product_Name, Product_Code, Product_Price, Product_Image, Product_Description) VALUES(@pnm, @pcod, @ppr, @pimg, @pdes) SELECT @@IDENTITY;";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnm", txtEName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcod", txt_productcode.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppr", txt_productprice.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdes", txt_productdescri.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pimg", imgByte);
            int Id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            lblResult.Text = String.Format("Employee ID is {0}", Id);
            conn.Close();

        }

        catch
        {
            lblResult.Text = "There was an error";
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Characters found after end of SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714696/characters-found-after-end-of-sql-statement)

Answer (score 0):

add semicolon before select @@identity. then try to excute. which means for insert statement one semicolon and for select on semi colon.

Comment: hi when i put semi colon betwn insert and select statement then i getting error Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: As I said in your previous post, you cannot execute two statements with MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Before "SELECT @@IDENTITY", you need a semi-colon.
Technically you're creating two SQL statements.
One for insert, and one for SELECT @@IDENTITY. That's why you need a semi-colon between those two queries.